# How to k-shuffle an array with STL?

Tags: c++, stl, shuffle

I am testing an algorithm that sorts a k-sorted array (every element is at most k-positions away from its correct sorted position).

I am having a hard time generating test data -- I can't randomly swap elements by k-positions because I may end up swapping an element twice. I could track which elements I swapped but then I need O(N) space.  I could also use a random-heap of size k + 1, but that sounds silly.

Is there anything built into the STL that can help me with this? This seems like a common problem, but my brief research only turned up algorithms for total shuffles (I think STL implements Fisher-Yates).

Comment: [std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: Next time please do more than "brief research" before asking us to do the rest of the work for you.

Comment: That shuffles the entire array, I need elements to stay at least k spots away from their correctly sorted position.

Comment: @racarate It doesn't shufle the entire array unless you want to, it shuffles a given range.

Comment: Additionally , next_permutation isn't great for test data because it only returns the same sequence every time.

Comment: Right, but if you shuffle k-elements at a time an element may end up more than k spots away from its proper place. (If for example, it falls in two adjacent k-ranges).

Comment: Take a look at [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) then.

Comment: @101010 Neither next_permutation nor shuffle does what the OP is asking for. This is actually trickier than it looks.

Comment: @preferencebean It looks like the OP has indeed thought about this one. It's harder than it seems.

Comment: @templatetypedef I know, The OP however doesn't show what she/he tried so far.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I didn't say it's easy, or that I know the answer. But "brief research" was a big red flag for me.

Comment: "This seems like a common problem." No, it doesn't. I think it is not an unprecedented problem, but I venture to guess that many programmers will never have encountered it.

Answer (score 1):

It feels odd problem since preparing random test data does not need to be ultra efficient, also the data may be usually whatever. You can have the test values as correct positions of those elements or pairs that give range of correct positions. For example array of pairs:

1. 1,1
2. 2,4
3. 2,4
4. 2,4
5. 5,6
6. 5,6
7. 7,7
   ...

Store the state of random generator somewhere.

Choose two random elements whose position is not more than k positions away of original position (or range) of other and swap. Repeat that N times and your test data is ready.

If you need to get same sequence later then restore the random generator state and repeat the algorithm.